# Any mock implementations of a SSL/TLS server and client?

Tags: open-source, ssl, mocks

I had learned about SMTP by studying a c# program of a [mock SMTP server](http://mocksmtpserver.codeplex.com) implementation. In the same fashion, I want to learn about SSL/TLS.

I am looking for mock implementations of a SSL/TLS server that is hackable, easy to setup, that can get me started on learning SSL/TLS. It can be in any language.

I am not looking for a reusable library since those libraries would abstract out the handshaking details. I am interested in learning those technical details through code.